# Why won't this file read in successfully?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I was trying to read in a .dat file that looks like this:

```
T001CD1              10000.00             2.5         2
T001CD2              50000.00             3.5         6
H407CD1             20000.00             2.0         1
M555CD1            30000.00             3.5         5
N423CD1             50000.00             3.0         4
N423CD2             60000.00             2.5         2
S602CD1              80000.00             4.0         8
H707CD1             25000.00             2.5         7
```

With this Code:

```
void readCdAccountInfo()
{
ifstream in_stream;


in_stream.open("CdAccounts.dat");

while (!in_stream.eof())
{ 
int i = 0;
string iDTemp;
float ratetemp;
int yeartemp;
double depotemp;
while (in_stream
    >> iDTemp
    >> depotemp
    >> ratetemp
    >> yeartemp
     )

{
    CCdAccount temp(iDTemp, depotemp, ratetemp, yeartemp);
    accounts[i] = temp;
    i++;
}

{
    if (in_stream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
        exit(1);
    }

    in_stream.close();
}}
}
```

ID, Deposit (private member), Rate, and Year are are all part of a class I have.

The only thing that pops up when I run my main is the input file failure message.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger, to see if it successfully went through the loop at all before failing?

Comment: this is the first time I see someone reporting "opening failed" after reading the entire file and right before closing it.

Comment: Reaching end of file sets the `eofbit` for a stream.  However, operations that attempt to read something (like `operator>>()`) also set the `failbit` if reaching end of file causes them to fail (i.e. to not receive input).   This will cause `in_stream.fail()` to become true when end of file is reached  by `in_stream >> iDTemp >> depotemp >> ratetemp >> yeartemp` in the `while` statement.

Comment: The outer `while` loop seems strange as your inner `while` already reads all records.

Answer (score 0):

First, check for opening error immediately after *opening* the file.

```
ifstream in_stream("CdAccounts.dat");
if (in_stream.fail())
{
    cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
    exit(1);
}
```

The outer loop `while (!in_stream.eof())` is obsolete, as you already check for stream errors in the inner loop correctly.

In the following code, I don't know the type of variable `accounts`, but it appears to be an array. It's not directly related to the issues you experience but that array may overflow if the file contains more records than you have reserved for your array. I suggest using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, which will resize automatically.

```
int i = 0;
string iDTemp;
float ratetemp;
int yeartemp;
double depotemp;

while (in_stream
    >> iDTemp
    >> depotemp
    >> ratetemp
    >> yeartemp
     )
{
    CCdAccount temp(iDTemp, depotemp, ratetemp, yeartemp);

    // Instead of this...
    accounts[i] = temp;
    i++;

    // ... I suggest declaring accounts as std::vector<CCdAccount>
    //     so you could add elements like this:
    // accounts.push_back( temp );
}
```

Next issue is in the error checking after this code. As commenter Peter pointed out:

> Reaching end of file sets the eofbit for a stream. However, operations
>   that attempt to read something (like operator>>()) also set the
>   failbit if reaching end of file causes them to fail (i.e. to not
>   receive input).

So to check only for *unexpected* read errors, we have to exclude the `eof` bit from the error condition:

```
if (in_stream.fail() && ! in_stream.eof())
{
    cout << "Input file reading failed.\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

At the end of the function there is no need to explicitly `close()` the stream as the destructor of the stream will automatically close the file when the scope ends. It's not an error to call `close()`, it's just obsolete.